# Debian (Lenny) how to Upgrade KVM to newer version?

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization

I have Debian Lenny installed with the following KVM  Version:

QEMU PC emulator version 0.9.1 (kvm-72), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard

=> The Problem is, this version has a confirmed bug, that is however already fixed in newer releases for KVM (Version KVM-79 and upwards).

What do I have to do to upgrade KVM to a newer version? Any hints and help a very much appreciated!

Thank you very much!!!
Jens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lenny [Backports](http://backports.debian.org/) has KVM version 0.12.5. This is the same version as is currently in Sid, so it should be fairly recent. [Here are complete instructions](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) on how to use Debian Backports in Lenny.

Comment: Hello Steven, thanks a million times!!! Looks very promising! thanks jens

Comment: I have a Jessie installation which has KVM version 2.1
I needed to install KVM version 2.5. This was available in jessie backports so I used the backports mechanism described in the response. 
However even after installing the package from backports, the kvm version still shows as 2.1. Is there some step I'm missing? 
Googled a lot, nothing helpful available.